# Angular2 cli: ng build --prod return RequestOptionsArgswas not found in '@angular/http/src/interfaces'

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular2 (2.4.9) not compilation production version.

If execution `ng b` in angular-cli my angular2 application successfully compilation and good work.
If execution `ng b --prod`, angular-cli return:

```
WARNING in ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
399:94-121 "export 'RequestOptionsArgs' (imported as 'import64') was not found in '@angular/http/src/interfaces'
```

and my angular2 application not execution (return exception)

I manually found `export interface RequestOptionsArgs` in node_modules/@angular/http/src/interfaces.d.ts.

Why? How fix it?

P.S. `--aot=false` not fix it